# Value of type AuthDataResult has no member providerID

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am expierencing this frustrating problem. This is beyond irritating that they make updates like this for Firebase with little to no specific documentation. I am getting the same error: Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'providerID' . and here is my code:

```
                if let user = user {
                    if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                        let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
                        DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: false)
                    } else {
                        let userData = ["provider": user.providerID, USER_IS_DRIVER: true, ACCOUNT_PICKUP_MODE_ENABLED: false, DRIVER_IS_ON_TRIP: false] as [String: Any]
                        DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that object called `user` in the code isn't a `FIRUser`, it is an `AuthDataResult` as indicated by the error.

```
let authdataresult = // the thing you were calling user
let user = authdataresult.user  // this is a FIRUser
let providerData = user.providerData  // this is FIRUserInfo
let providerId = providerData.providerId
```

Comment: Thank you very much Danh for your answer!!  How can I use it in my code? I'm new in the coding

Comment: Sure @Ryan, use the code I've suggested to get providerId, and replace `user.providerId` with just `providerId`

Comment: Thanks!! I replaced

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add another "user" after the first user. Not sure why Google made this change in the most recent Firebase update.

```
let userData = ["provider": user.user.providerID, "email": user.user.email]
DataService.instance.createDBUser(uid: user.user.uid, userData: userData as Dictionary<String, Any>)
userCreationComplete(true, nil)
```